# Change jquery datatables default row count shown

Tags: jquery, numbers, datatables, rows

By default, datatables has 4 sizes of records to show: 10,25,50,100.

A) Is there a way to change this? I tried editing the jquery file to change the array to [30,60,90,120] itself and this destroyed it.

B) Is there a way to set the default selection size say to 50 (instead of 10) of this selector upon initializing when jquery builds it?

I can't find either of these items in the documentation.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Update because this answer seems to get some views] --

**Updated Answer:**

In later versions (I believe 1.10+), the API naming conventions changed, ditching the Hungarian notation. I believe the old conventions are aliased for compatibility, but the current conventions are:

```
lengthMenu
pageLength
```

Thus, the updated answers are:

A) it's the `lengthMenu` parameter: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu

For example, here's how I have one of mine set:

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],
```

B) pageLength https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength -- optionally set this to whatever your default should be.

```
"pageLength" : 25,
```

---

**Original Answer**

A) It's the `aLengthMenu` parameter: http://datatables.net/ref#aLengthMenu

For example, here's how I have one of mine set:

```
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],
```

B) `iDisplayLength` -- set this parameter to whatever your default should be

Comment: Is there any event fired, when the user selects another length?

Comment: Here are the events that are fired with the current version of datatables: https://datatables.net/reference/event/

Answer (score 3):

- **DataTables 1.10+**

  Use [`lengthMenu`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) to define a list of available page lengths and *optionally* [`pageLength`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) to set initial page length.

  If [`pageLength`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) is not specified, it will be automatically set to the first value given in array specified by [`lengthMenu`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu).

  ```js
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     lengthMenu: [ [2, 4, 8, -1], [2, 4, 8, "All"] ],
     pageLength: 4
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dpac4kh/219/) for code and demonstration.

---

- **DataTables 1.9**

  Use [`aLengthMenu`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) to define a list of available page lengths and [`iDisplayLength`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength) to set initial page length.

  ```js
  var table = $('#example').dataTable({
     "aLengthMenu": [ [2, 4, 8, -1], [2, 4, 8, "All"] ],
     "iDisplayLength" : 4,        
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67tzkca2/92/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable Version : 1.9.4
What works for me is this:-
First I searched the Jquery.dataTables file which is mostly placed in the js folder. Then I search for "aLengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ], and changed it according to my requirements i.e.  "aLengthMenu": [ 50, 75, 100, 125 ]. Thereafter I searched for "iDisplayLength" and wherever its value is shown as 10 (4 to 5 places), I changed it to 50 and save. Dropdown on my index page started showing row option as 50,75,100,125 in place of 10,25,50,100 with default option selected as 50.